# How do I use Butterknife's new butterknife.debuggable processor option?

Tags: android, butterknife

Butterknife 8.8.0 introduced the new processor option `butterknife.debuggable` ([link to changelog](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)). By default, it's true. Where do I set it to false in my build.gradle file? I tried placing it in my `defaultConfig`, but I keep getting the error:

`Could not get unknown property 'butterknife'...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Looks like Butterknife mirrors the `debuggable` attribute of your current config. So setting `debuggable` inside your `defaultConfig` or other build type should also set `butterknife.debuggable`.</s>

EDIT: My initial answer was incorrect. Add this to your Gradle build type to modify the `butterknife.debuggable` flag:

`javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.arguments['butterknife.debuggable'] = 'false'`